# A complex JS validation for membership ID

Tags: javascript, validation

Our users have a membership ID that is generated based on some sort of logic. We would like to use JS to validate if they are putting in the right membership code prior to passing on to server.

Please see below:

Below is an example of the Modulus 7 algorithm used to validate our membership number. Membership numbers passed to us in the transaction file (see format above) should conform to this.

```
8 digit number – (7 x Quotient (8 digit number / 7))

If 8 digit number = 71231231----------------------------- (A)

E.g. 71231231 – (7 x Quotient (71231231 / 7))

= 71231231 – (7 x Quotient (10175890.142857142857142857142857))

= 71231231 – (7 x 10175890)

= 71231231 - 71231230

= 1 ---------------------------------------------------- (B)

Therefore the membership number = (B) concatenated to the end of  (A) = 712312311
```

Example of correct numbers:
00999999033, 00999999044

Comment: to be completely honest I have just tried to understand it, and have not yet succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing your expected algorithm,

Your membership ID has 9 digit number without leading zeros. This number is made by trailing the modulo of 7 of the first 8 digits right after the same 8 digits.

Example:

```
  A valid ID:  00999999044

  The breakdown of this should be [99999904] [99999904 mod 7]
```

You can check this by the following function of JS

```
function checkID(id) {

   id = parseInt(id);

   if (String(id).length !== 9)              //Fail if n digits are incorrect
      return false;

   var firstEight = Math.floor(id / 10);     //Get first 8 digits
   var modulo7 = firstEight % 7;             //Get the modulo

   return id === firstEight * 10 + modulo7;  //Check if modulo is after the 8 digits 

}
```

Comment: Thank you, we will check this and I will mark correct accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is have a form that does your modulus logic before submitting the data to the server.

HTML

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="membershipNumber" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var membershipNumber = document.getElementById('membershipNumber').value;
  var newMembershipNumber = membershipNumber + String(setModulus7(membershipNumber));

  //send new membership number to backend   
  console.log(newMembershipNumber);
});

function setModulus7(value) {
  var checkDigit = value - (7 * (Math.floor(value / 7)));
  return checkDigit;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34d9o7rf/1

Comment: This is not what the OP ask